# Solr - Bringing back snippets from indexed data

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a Solr/Lucene set up where I have indexed a set of documents (MS Word files) and can happily search the content of these documents. However I would like to return a snippet from within the content of the document which shows where the matching line (+/- 5 words from the match term) is. I have tried to follow a range of Google hits but my indexing does not seem to have a direct access to the "content".

Can anyone give me some basic and simple pointers to where I might have made any errors on this - I have based all my work so far on the guidance and examples of the Solr Reference Guide - so I am not sure if the issue is in the search parameters or the original index.

I am doing this to create a clear set of user requirements for building an end solution rather than creating the end solution myself, so I am no expert on the tools and do not need to become one, just need to evidence what is possible with this tool set.

Comment: Solr lets you return snippets with terms highlighted. https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/highlighting.html Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: It is - but when i try and follow the information there the best i can return is the name of the document, but no actual snippet of the text from within the document. So if I take their example query/url from "Highlighting in the Query Response"
and hack it in line with my index i do not get the highlighting in line with their example results, especially with the <em> html tags.

Comment: Do you have a `content` field defined in your index? Without it you won't get the verbatim content stored for the field, as the regular search field doesn't contain the actual content (just the indexed format). You can [use `f.map.content` when indexing to move the content](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_1/uploading-data-with-solr-cell-using-apache-tika.html#solr-cell-input-parameters) into a different field.

Comment: You will have to give some more details about your index, and schema. it's probably a missed setting somewhere. Can you post your schema? Or at least the field which you are trying to highlight?

Comment: Matslindh - I think you probably have it. I had assumed the content would be available automatically, but as it looks like I need to push that through. I will try and get around to testing this over the next few days, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As MatsLindh noted above the issue was that the config was not drawing across the actual content of the Tika parse into a specific field, and so there was no full content of the text to display and highlight

To resolve this I followed the link (https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_1/uploading-data-with-solr-cell-using-apache-tika.html#configuring-the-solr-extractingrequesthandler) to the guidance documents and reviewed the part on fmap and used the example given for Last Modified Date as a guide on what to apply.

I then went to my solrconfig.xml file in the relevant core folder and added in the following line in the code beneath an already present fmap entry:

```
  <str name="fmap.content">testcontent</str>
```

I had previously set up the testcontent field under the solr web interface in my core. I then re-ran my indexing line via a command prompt and that seemed to do the trick in terms of pulling out the basic content and rapping it with a basic emphasis.

All thanks for the input on this - still a lot more I want to test to help develop a clear requirement set but this really helps prove some of the basics are not complected.